# Limiting amount of statements sent to database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Is there a way to combine/pool many insert or update statements to send them once to the database?

Until I figure out a network latency issue, I'm curious to see if it's possible to send an insert or update statement containing many rows from CakePHP limiting the back and forth between the database.

**Edit #1**

- Initial solution was using entities with Table->save()
- Built array of all entities then used Table->saveMany()

Both cases, individual statements are sent to the db.

Comment: Prepared and parameterised queries

Comment: May want to use UPDATE-SELECT statements to update based on other table/column data. Not sure what your current queries look like.

Comment: If you're using `INSERT` with actual values, you can do many rows at a time

Comment: @emgx I'm building entities and saving them using the table. I've also tried building an array, patching and using saveMany. It all seems to send individual inserts or updates.

Comment: @robeyre what option when using save() would enable this to happen? Or perhaps it's saveMany()?

Answer (score 1):

The ORM will always use separate `INSERT` statements, unless you rewrite it, that's the way it rolls.

If you want to issue insert statements with multiple rows in the `VALUES` clause, then you'd have to manually generate insert queries instead of using the ORM's saving methods. This will come with certain drawbacks of course, such as no ORM events being dispatched, application rules not being applied automatically, etc.

The closest the ORM does to "combining" statements, is using transactions with `saveMany()`, which it will do by default in case the used DBMS supports it.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Inserting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data)**

Comment: that's not bad actually, being able to append to the query using values().